# how to parse json from url?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, cordova

Hello every one i am working on the app where i need to parse the json using java script for parsing the json. I google it a lot i try almost from two the 2 3 hour but not getting any proper answer which i am looking .Below code is what i am try .

my code is :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script>

$(function() {

var entries = [];
var dmJSON = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fcallme.myshareus.nl%2FAPI%2FgetGroups.php%3FAPIkey%3Dte7gRRT8Ut2VYW%26InitiatorId%3D0000001%26AccountId%3D00550%26Role%3D1%0A%27&format=json&diagnostics=true?callback=?";
$.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
   $.each(data.entity, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.content + "</td>" +  "</tr>"
       $(tblRow).appendTo("#entrydata tbody");
 });

});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "entrydata" border="1">
<thead>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>

    </thead>
  <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

i am not getting any responce.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the URL:

```
?callback=?
```

should be:

```
&callback=?
```

In URLs, `?` is used to separate the parameters from the pathname, and `&` is used to separate parameters from each other.

Comment: thank you sir for answering my question but i change it with &callback=? but still not getting the response.